# Wordpress search via metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, search

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a custom search form to search for posts based on various metadata.

This code contains the settings for the WordPress search: http://pastebin.com/5dj16Atj
The references to the custom fields are all in there.

This code is referenced in the file above and contains the actual layout for the custom search form: http://pastie.org/private/yebozm9kaqazywkilr8fkq

My main problem is that only 3 fields work in the custom search form, namely; Price Range and Area. The remaining fields such as Property Type (srch_ptype), age (srch_age) and City just don't show up as criteria in the search. I would like all the fields to be functional and get included as criteria when people are searching.
Kindly take a look at both files to see what I have gotten wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
adomnom was kind enough to suggest that i use wp_query for the search. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to connect the search form with the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress search code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754077/wordpress-search-code)

Comment: Any more contributions? I still need help with it please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with markratledge on this one. I'd recommend looking into [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), or even overriding the default wordpress search with special hooks.

You should be able to do something like...

---

Define the parameters of the search (more at [WP_Query Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)) and run it

```
$searchArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'srch_age',   'value' => $_REQUEST['srch_age'] ),
        array( 'key' => 'srch_ptype', 'value' => $_REQUEST['srch_ptype'] )
        // ... Add as many other criteria as you need
    )
);

query_posts( $searchArgs );
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
...
```

Comment: Thanks adomnom! Yours is the first helpful answer I've gotten.
Can you please provide more guidance on how to use the search form with wp_query? I'm sorry but I'm quite new at using WordPress and the initial coding was done by someone else but I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Hi Guys, still hoping I'll get some more info in this. Can anyone please help out with more information?

Comment: Hello @adomnom, I tried your suggestion. Here's my code:
    <?php $posts=query_posts($query_string .
    '&posts_per_page=5','post_type=post'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <h1>Results</h1>
<?php
$searchArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'srch_age',   'value' => $_REQUEST['srch_age'] ),
        array( 'key' => 'srch_ptype', 'value' => $_REQUEST['srch_ptype'] )
    )
);
query_posts( $searchArgs );
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

It still doesn't search the custom fields